# confusing "cannot redeclare class" error (PHP)

Tags: php, autoload, redeclare

I have a strange issue. I have a static method that loads classes (load_library). When it loads a particular class, it gives me a "cannot redeclare class" fatal error, but when testing whether the class exists right before using the load_library method to load it, it says the class does not exist. The `load_library` method works elsewhere without such errors.

If I take the load_library call out, it says it cannot find the class when the class is actually used a few lines later. Stranger still, if I take out my registered class `autoload` function instead, everything works perfectly, even though this `autoload` function doesn't even check the directory that the class I'm trying to load is in.

It's a complicated problem involving many files so it is hard to post code, but does this problem smell familiar to anyone out there?

My load_library method:

```
    public static function load_library($name) {
        if (!class_exists($name)) {
            if (file_exists('application/libraries/' . $name . '.php')) {
                include('application/libraries/' . $name . '.php');
            } else {
                trigger_error('Request made for non-existant library ('.$name.').', E_USER_ERROR);
            }
        }
    }
```

My call to the load_library method:

```
lev::load_library('lev_unit_tester/lev_base_test');
```

My registered autoload method:

```
    public static function autoloader($name) {
        if (class_exists($name)) return;
        if (file_exists('application/libraries/' . $name . '.php')) {
            include('application/libraries/' . $name . '.php');
        }
    }
```

The class I am trying to load (this is where the error occurs):

```
abstract class lev_base_test {

}
```

The actual error message:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class lev_base_test in /some/path/application/libraries/lev_unit_tester/lev_base_test.php on line 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
// Check to see whether the include declared the class
    if (!class_exists($class, false)){..}
```

Comment: when i do the include is when I get the error. i checked to see if the class existed before i did the include.

Answer (score 0):

Your are calling your `load_library` method this way :

```
lev::load_library('lev_unit_tester/lev_base_test');
```

Which means you are testing, with `class_exists()`, if there is a class called `lev_unit_tester/lev_base_test` -- which is probably not quite the case : that's not a valid name for a class.

So `class_exists()` returns `false` ; and, so, you try to include the file that contains your class every time the `load_library` method is called.

There is no problem when you are using autoloading, because PHP will only call your autoloader when it you try to use a class which has not been defined : once the file that correspond to a class has been included, the autoloaded will not be called for that class again.

Comment: strange : it seems that `class_exists()` receives the same `$name` parameter as the `load_library` method -- and the fatal error message you get shows that `$name` is 'lev_unit_tester/lev_base_test'

Comment: the class_exists call uses a literal string as an argument, where th load_library call uses a path/filename as an argument...

Comment: my class exists call looked like this: if (!class_exists('lev_base_test')) echo 'blahblahblah';

Comment: im not sure you read the question very thouroughly. I know how the autoload works. the autoload cannot possibly even load this class file, because it does not check that directory for class files at all. the only reason i mention it, is because it's removal seems to stop the error from happening, which does not make sense at all.

Comment: It's a bit early, so I might be wrong, but I don't see that hard-coded `class_exists()` call in the code you posted ; instead, I see `class_exists($name)`, with `$name` being passed to `lev::load_library` as `'lev_unit_tester/lev_base_test'`

Comment: ah, i see your point, and that is a potential bug, but it is not what is causing my problem, since i only call the load_library on this class once.

Comment: the hardcoded one i was testing with occured before the load_library call.

Comment: i understand now... class_exists calls an autoload function automatically... I dislike that.